# um função em Haskell que recebe com entrada um numero n e uma lista e retorna a quantidade de número maiores que n

Tags: haskell

```
maiores :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
maiores _ [] = 0
maiores n (x:xs)
```

alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer?

Answer (score 2):

Há diversas formas de fazer, além da já citada solução usando guardas.

Filtrando os maiores que n e depois contando o número de elementos

List comprehension:

```hs
maiores :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
maiores n xs = length [x | x<-xs, x > n]
```

Filter:

```hs
maiores :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
maiores n xs = length $ filter (>n) xs
```

Ou você pode fazer uma solução recursiva com Ifs (muito parecida com a solução que usa guardas):

```hs
maiores :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
maiores _ [] = 0
maiores n (x:xs) =
  if x > n
    then 1 + maiores n xs
    else maiores n xs
```

Comment: Boa! já agora um pouco mais estranha: `maiores n=length . filter (>n)`

Answer (score 1):

Pra resolver esse problema você precisa usar **guardas**, dessa forma você consegue testar uma condição.

Como haskell é um linguagem puramente funcional o ideal é utilizar recursão.

Sendo `(x:xs)` a lista inteira onde `x` é o primeiro elemento e `xs` é o restante da lista, você precisa comparar se o primeiro elemento é maior que `n` se for você vai somar `1` ao retorno do resultado da função com o restante da lista, caso não for você só precisa chamar a função recursivamente sem adicionar nada ao retorno.

Lembrando que é possível fazer essa soma ao retorno da função, pois seu retorno também é `Int`

**Função completa:**

```
maiores :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
maiores _ [] = 0
maiores n (x:xs)
    | x > n = 1 + maiores n xs
    | otherwise = maiores n xs
```